# Can I use a compiled query in a web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

I have a WCF service with a select method requiring only an id.  I need to use several (20+) load options to get everything I need to return so I would think this make a pretty complicated query and compiling it would be a good idea.  the only way I have found so far is to create a static data context and load options to use with the compiled query.  If I don't it complains about using a different context than it was compiled with.  So that makes my question should I do this?  Will having a static data context on a web service cause issues?  It would only be used for this method.  All other methods create their own.  I'm just afraid I might end up paying for this decision down the road so any tips would be great!  Thanks!

```
    private static DataLoadOptions loadOptions = GetDataLoadOpt();

    private static readonly Func<ItemsDataContext, int, Data.Item> SelectItem =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((ItemsDataContext DataContext, int ItemId) =>
            DataContext.Items.Where(r => r.ItemID == ItemId).FirstOrDefault());

    private static DataLoadOptions GetDataLoadOpt()
    {
        var loadOpts = new System.Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions();
        loadOpts.LoadWith<Data.Item>(d => d.ItemProp);
        .
        .
        .
        return loadOpts;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code? I can't think of why it would need a data-context to compile. I have 30+ compiled queries in one of my projects which is done without a context.

Comment: Hope that is enough to get an idea what I'm working with

Comment: can you also post the exception and stack trace?

Comment: The exception I get is "Query was compiled for a different mapping source than the one associated with the specified DataContext." which makes sense because it is different being that the context is created in the web service method.  If I make the context static it works.  I just think it would be a bad idea to have a static datacontext in a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web service calls are distinct. I haven't found that having a shared, static context saves any time because the call ends up spinning up a new instance anyway. And I also have several objects that have very large, complicated loadoptions stacks in a few of my projects. In some cases, I have a bit of performance drop because I'm bringing back so many tables, but if the joins are strong (well-designed DB), then it's not too bad.